# Import cassandra schema script doesn't run in docker when using volumes

Tags: cassandra, docker, volumes

I have a problem on using cassandra in Docker
I've created a Dockerfile this like

```
----------------------Dockerfile----------------------------
FROM spotify/cassandra:base
COPY  cassandra-schema.cql /tmp/

COPY cassandra-init.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY cassandra-singlenode.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x  /usr/local/bin/cassandra-init.sh
RUN chmod +x  /usr/local/bin/cassandra-singlenode.sh
#import schema
RUN /usr/local/bin/cassandra-init.sh
EXPOSE 9160
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/cassandra-singlenode.sh"]
```

If i have use

```
docker run  --name cassandradb cassandra
```

everything works properly but if i use

```
docker run  --name cassandradb -v /opt/argus/cassandra/data/:/var/lib/cassandra/data -v /opt/argus/cassandra/commitlog:/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog cassandra
```

the cassandra starts but the /usr/local/bin/cassandra-init.sh doesn't import my scheam

Any idea?

These are my files contents

```
 ------------------cassandra-init.sh-----------------------
echo "===================================================="
echo "starting running cqlsh"
echo "===================================================="

cassandra  &
while : ;do

  # Get the status of this machine from the Cassandra nodetool
  STATUS=`nodetool status | grep 'UN' | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo $STATUS
  # Once the status is Up and Normal, then we are ready
  if [ $STATUS = "UN" ]; then
        cqlsh -f /tmp/cassandra-schema.cql
        break
  fi

  sleep 1;

done



----------------------------cassandra-singlenode.sh--------------------------------
echo "=============================================== Change configuration ====================================================="
IP=`hostname --ip-address`
SEEDS=`env | grep CASS[0-9]_PORT_9042_TCP_ADDR | sed 's/CASS[0-9]_PORT_9042_TCP_ADDR=//g' | sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/,/' -e ta`

if [ -z "$SEEDS" ]; then
  SEEDS=$IP
fi

    echo "Listening on: "$IP
    echo "Found seeds: "$SEEDS

    # Setup Cassandra
    CONFIG=/etc/cassandra/
    sed -i -e "s/^listen_address.*/listen_address: $IP/"            $CONFIG/cassandra.yaml
    sed -i -e "s/^rpc_address.*/rpc_address: 0.0.0.0/"              $CONFIG/cassandra.yaml
    sed -i -e "s/- seeds: \"127.0.0.1\"/- seeds: \"$SEEDS\"/"       $CONFIG/cassandra.yaml
    sed -i -e "s/# JVM_OPTS=\"$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public name>\"/ JVM_OPTS=\"$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$IP\"/" $CONFIG/cassandra-env.sh





echo "=========================================================================================================================="
echo "starting running cassandra server"
echo "=========================================================================================================================="

cassandra  &
while :
do
        echo "Cassandra running, Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
        sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Are you directly on Linux? Or through a Linux VM on Windows or Mac?

Comment: VonC: I'm directly on the ubuntu